# GPS Stops working after few hours

Tags: android, gps

I am developing an android application. Here on every one minute interval I am fetching latitude & longitude & uploading them to server. My Application works fine on HTC Tatto Phone. but same application when I launch to Reliance Tablet, It stops working after few hours. My Application or even device's own GPS Application stops fetching GPS. so what could be the reason for same ? Device has enough battery power.

Comment: Drivers in the phone may be buggy, I have seen this when my personal Droid 3 phone stops pinging the gps, when I am requesting. A simple toggle of GPS fixes this. May be related.

Comment: can you provide logcat details. might be due to some exception it is happening.or may be you are removing updated after some time.

Comment: sorry but I do not have Logcat details.

Comment: I recommend to check whether the service (I guess you are running a service, do you?) is destroyed. Just output a messege to LogCat in onDestry(). Another suggestion is the wake lock: If set it prevents the device from shutting down the CPU to save battery.

Comment: You'll have to record your LogCat data for hours and then analyze it to check for GPS chipset failures or any abberations. On a sidenote `1)` I hope you're informing your users that you're tracking them on a server `2)` 4 minutes is better than 1 minute from a battery point of view.

Comment: Did you find Solution ??